# How much trouble will a Nuclear type Pokemon cause me?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

According to the [documentation](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Nuclear_(type)), Nuclear type Pokemon

> are much more aggressive than normal Pokémon, and have been likened to mindless monsters that will attack anything in sight. You can catch them, but they disobey orders and may even attack their trainer

I got one [Trawpint](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Trawpint) at the first Power Plant (Epsilon? Can't remember.)

How often those Nuclear Pokemon go rogue, disobey orders, and cause trouble?

Or is that text more a role-playing description? That is, the Pokemon won't actually cause any trouble at all?

Answer (score 2):

That same documentation also says there are several pure Nuclear type Pokémon that will never disobey; they are essentially like normal Pokémon except that they are Nuclear type.

The Trawpint you caught is one of the rogue ones that may disobey. If it becomes particularly troublesome, I'd recommend catching one of the pures that won't give you any trouble.

The list of pures that will never disobey is: Nucleon, Xenomite, Xenogen, Xenoqueen, Hazma, Urayne, and Geigeroach. These are naturally Nuclear type and are therefore not corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

They occasionally obey, but I've yet to have my nuclear-type Pokemon actually attack me. It's also odd that when it "disobeys" orders, it does exactly what I say. It may also occasionally turn away and do nothing at all, but this information is all from two battles with my nuclear-type Pokemon. I've also heard that later in the game they can be "cured" and will then obey, but their coloring and type remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

After you done the Nuclear Plant Zeta Quest you can go to the Bealbeach City's Ranger Station and go down stairs and finally ask P.Cypress to cure your Nuclear type Pokemon so it will always listen to your orders. This is real because i've already done this and also read the Pokemon Uranium wiki.